# Postfix autoresponder without MySQL

Tags: postfix, auto-reply

I know there is this question on ServerFault, but it doesn't respond to mine. (http://www.howtoforge.com/autoresponders_for_virtual_postfix_users)

I want to set up an automatic reply robot on my linux server (no idea what distro), but I don't want any MySQL stuff in it. I just want it as simple as possible. Something like this:

```
IF (receiver_email EQUAL TO "something@domain.com") THEN
    SEND_AUTORESPONSE()
ENDIF
```

Is this possible? Is there any autoresponder out there that would do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there are even more than one. Use [vacation](http://sourceforge.net/projects/vacation/) and set it up as usual or look into other [autoreply software](http://www.postfix.org/addon.html#autoreply).

Beware of having a general auto-reply functionality independent of the message content. Make sure you have scanned and eliminated all Spam/Viruses before. Otherwise you auto-reply to Spam which is a very bad idea.

Comment: I wanted to avoid using vacation, as I am having a lot of difficulties installing/ **configuring** it, but I see there's not much choice. Thanks.